# Application crashes on dialogue close with threads running

Tags: c++, mfc

In my application I have a modal dialog which contains about 20 different combo boxes which are bind to certain fields in the databases. The database is huge and on the loading of dialog I have to load all the combo boxes from the databases. So I setup 20 threads (1 each for every combo box).

Everything works fine, but the problem only occurs when the user closes the dialog with close or cancel button or OK button while the threads are running; in that case the application crashes.

I have tried to terminate the threads prematurely as well but that does not help. Here is the thread termination code

```
if(m_iNoOfThreadsCompleted != m_iTotalThreads)      
{
        for(int i = 0; i < m_iTotalThreads - 1; i++)
    {
            if (m_threads[i] != NULL)
        {
            GetExitCodeThread(m_threads[i]->m_hThread, &exit_code);
            if(exit_code == STILL_ACTIVE)
                CloseHandle(m_threads[i]->m_hThread);
        }
        if(m_iNoOfThreadsCompleted == m_iTotalThreads)
            break;
    }
}
```

What is the issue? Or do I need to use a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronizing threads is generally done using events.

```
// Before Creating threads
HANDLE hEndEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);
// Pass handle to threads
```

Then on termination

```
SetEvent(hEndEvent);
WaitForMultipleObjects(m_iTotalThreads,m_threads,TRUE,INFINITE); // Wait for all threads to end

// Loop through and close all the thread handles
```

Note that you need to be occasionally looking for the end event to be set otherwise your threads won't end.

```
// In Thread
if (WaitForSingleObject(hEndEvent,0)==WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    // Clean up
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried using approch but still my application is crashing. I am setting the event on OnDestroy event. So my thread function is not hit once the OnDestroy is called. is there any other event handler I can put this code in?
P.S: I am not putting the code behind a button or as such because my dialog a modeless so even if the main application closes my dialog/application should close gracefully.

Comment: If your threads depend on having a valid window handle (OLE generally does), try ending the threads before calling CDialog::OnDestroy.

Answer (score 1):

`CloseHandle` does not terminate the thread.  You can call `TerminateThread` but it's not the nicest thing to do...

What is normal is to provide your threads with a manual-reset event object that signals a shutdown is taking place.  Sometimes it's also good to have a flag so that threads can abort lenghty operations.  The threads carry on their work as usual, and whenever they have to wait on some object, you include the shutdown event object in that wait.

So the procedure on exit is normally to do this:

1. Set the shutdown flag
2. Signal the shutdown event
3. Resume all threads (in case any are suspended)
4. `WaitForMultipleObjects` on all thread handles, with an appropriate timeout
5. Call `TerminateThread` on any threads that did not exit within the timeout
6. Close all thread handles
7. Destroy the shutdown event

This approach requires that threads are created with `_beginthreadex`, so that you are responsible for closing the handles.  The benefit of this is that you can wait on threads, even after they've exited (of course an exited thread is already in the signaled state).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what paddy describes another approach would be to instead of having 20 threads that load the comboboxes to just have one thread that loads. By having 20 threads you may not be speeding up things anyway depending on your database library.

Then when that thread is loading periodically (like between each checkbox) check whether user pressed cancel or not, if so then stop processing and exit the thread.

This would make the handling less complicated than managing 20 threads IMHO.